# JPQL query to get last 10 days of data

Tags: spring-boot, jpql

I have a simple sql query

SELECT * FROM survey t WHERE t.date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -10 DAY);

or

SELECT * FROM survey t WHERE t.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY )

What is the equaivalent of getting the data using JPQL query for the where condition

Answer (score 0):

Incase if it is useful to anyone

BETWEEN is the word

Call like this in service

```
repository.getData(new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 10*24*60*60*1000L), new java.util.Date());
```

in the repositary

```
  @Query(SELECT * FROM survey t WHERE t.date BETWEEN :startDate 
 AND :endDate) 
 List<Object[]> data(@Param("startDate") Date startDate,@Param("endDate") Date endDate);
```